# Memory in C (array structures)

Tags: c, memory, realloc, calloc

i have dynamic array of structures.

```
struct Pacient
{
    char name[30];
    char surname[30];
    char middleName[30];
    char nationality[30];
    float height;
    float weight;
    char phone[30];
    struct Date  {
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
    }dateOfBirth;
    struct Adress {
        char city[30];
        char street[30];
        int numberOfHouse;
    } adress;
    struct Hospital {
        int numberOfHospital;
        char nameOfOffice[30];
        int numberOfMedicalCart;
        char groupOfBlood[10];
        char nameOfDiagnosis[30];
    }hospitalInfo;
};
```

Me need add,delete element from array.

```
Pacient* pacients;
pacients = (Pacient*)calloc(count, sizeof(Pacient));
```

^ my declaration of array, count - size of array.

I made func addNewPacient and deleteLastElement.

```
 void addNewPacient() {
    count++;
    pacients = (Pacient*)realloc(pacients, sizeof(Pacient)*count );
    ......//many scanf...
}
void removeLastElement() {
    count--;
    pacients = (Pacient*)realloc(pacients, count * sizeof(Pacient*));
}
```

For start, i input info about (example) 3 users. *Ivan, Petro and Grisha.*
I call method printAll() and all be fine.   **{Ivan ....., Peto ...., Grisha ....}**

After i can call method addNewPacient() (Nazar) and all will be fine again. **{Ivan ....., Peto ...., Grisha ...., Nazar....}**
But when i remove last element from array, all almost will be fine ALMOST.
**{Ivan ......, Petro ....., Grisdksaldaskfpwqe###221 ......}**
Penult element distorted. 
I think i have problem with deleteLastElement(), help plz)

Comment: where is `pacients` declared? global?

Comment: `Pacient* pacients;...` needs `Pacient` --> `struct Pacient`?

Comment: I found bug, in pacients = (Pacient*)realloc(pacients, count * sizeof(Pacient*)); need delete * after Pacient. Senq)

Comment: see: you don't even need to ask. you found that yourself :)

Comment: bit why not using lists? with lists you would simplify memory management as well as records management (eg remove an entry that is not the last one)

Answer (score 2):

you're right: your list shrink code has a problem:

```
pacients = (Pacient*)realloc(pacients, count * sizeof(Pacient*));
```

you're passing the size of the *pointer* not of the *structure*. You did well for growth function. Pass the actual size of the structure or you'll have a lot less memory to work with, which explains the trashed end elements.

Now that I pointed that out, the fix is easy: just copy the line above (should have done that in the first place or done a macro to avoid copying/pasting):

```
pacients = realloc(pacients, count * sizeof(Pacient));
```